# Blurring images server side or with CSS

Tags: python, css

I have a website which has images uploaded by the user which is blurred with the following CSS:

```
.blur {
  -webkit-filter:blur(40px);
  filter:blur(40px);
  filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius='40')
}
```

However there is little support with this as [seen here](http://caniuse.com/#search=filters).

One way of allowing this to work across all browsers is by blurring the image server side (I'm using Python with Flask so I could use the pill Python library, blur it and then save that image.)

However there are also disadvantages to using this such as greater storage costs.

So, should I blur the images server side or is there a CSS workaround? Thanks.

Comment: are you able to achieve blur with css? then yes, you should do it with css.

Comment: Filters actually have fairly good support (apart from IE) and what those users don't have they won't miss - http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters

Comment: If you need to support old browsers - http://msurguy.github.io/background-blur/, or some similar plugin...

Comment: If blurring is for security reasons: NO, don't use CSS as everyone would be able to download the unblurred (original) image. If it is only for aesthetics, it is up to you to decide what is a reasonable fallback.

Comment: @Paulie_D is there a workaround for IE8+?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but it came up in my search. For anyone else looking into this, one thing to consider is the client-side processor overhead required to blur with a radius of 40px. I am building a page that blurs a scrolling section over a fixed background (this is for visual effect, not to obscure content/security), and while scrolling, my CPU usage was unusually high. This was causing perceptible lag on a recent model laptop. I ended up going with server-side pre-blurred images instead of the CSS filter, and CPU usage while scrolling the page is substantially lower.

In general, as @taesu noted, a visual effect like this is usually best done with CSS, but be sure you're not incurring a performance hit that negatively impacts your user experience.